# How to draw a large-scale network graph using networkx（Occlusion issue）

Tags: networking, graph, networkx

There is a social network graph with more than 6000 vertices and tens of thousands of edges. It is drawn directly by Python networkx as shown in the figure. **How to make her look better and clearer, and make interactive information more obvious?**

[The disorganized graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otSgm.png)

And what I have done is try to **decrease all those transparencies or make the line thinner.** But it looks like the result is still disorganized. Because my screen is fixed, no matter what I do, the lines are very dense just like the pic before.

My little thinking is **I don't try to make all lines clear but to make some lines clear**. It may be like, increasing the opacity of some lines which are more important or more prominent structures, decreasing the opacity of other lines, **like to calculate the edge_betweenness value for every edge and using this to set the transparency of each line**. The code is below:

```
G = nx.read_gml('data\\lesmis.gml')

cent = edge_betweenness_centrality(G)
#node_pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
node_pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
#node_pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,node_pos,**options)#draw nodes
[nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,node_pos,edgelist=[key],alpha=np.amin([1,value*100]),width=2) for key,value in cent.items()] #loop through edges and draw them

plt.show()
```

But the result is just so so. Is there anyone who can give me some methods, or just a little advice or possible ideas？

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a tricky problem!  One possibility is to avoid the problem of visualizing all edges at once, and instead produce an *interactive* plot that allows you to highlight the edges for each node independently.  The [`hvplot` package](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/NetworkX.html) is capable of generating interactive plots with `bokeh` for visualizing networks.  It might be worth looking at.

Comment: Another option might be to use [DataShader](https://datashader.org/user_guide/Networks.html) to visualize your network, with special "edge bundling" layout options.  Personally, I think those figures are beautiful, but not so interpretable.  Still, if you find a clever way to arrange the nodes in your graph, perhaps the bundled edges might not be too confusing.